# Filter two big files with many columns

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have two big files (millions of lines) and I don't have access to a database. It is necessary for me use bash.

The first file is something like:

```
NUMBER   CODE   CAMP2
1222     aa132   3264
1223     ab124   4283
1224     af121   6224
1225     ag172   9235
1226     aw183   1229
           .
           .
           .
```

And my second file is something like:

```
NUMBER   NAME    CAMP3
1222     Juan     1111
1223     Carlos   2222
1225     Jesus    4444
1226     Mosies   5555
           .
           .
           .
```

And I need to cross the files by the NUMBER:

```
NUMBER   CODE   CAMP2   NAME     CAMP3
1222     aa132   3264   Juan     1111
1223     ab124   4283   Carlos   2222
1225     ag172   9235   Jesus    4444
1226     aw183   1229   Mosies   5555
```

I try with a for read line by line, but it take a lot of time.

`comm` is not possible because are many columns.

The two files do not have the same number of lines. There are lines in the first file that are not in the second file, and vice versa.

My code so far is very simple:

```
while read line
do
   numer=$(echo $line | awk -F" " '{print $1}')
   search=$(grep $numer file2)
   if [ ! -z $search ]; then
       echo $line" "$search > file_output
   fi
done < file1
```

The `while` works, but takes a long time.

Comment: You should [edit] the question and post the code you already have.

Comment: my code is very easy, is something like:
`while read line
do
   numer=$(echo $line | awk -F" " '{print $1}')
   search=$(grep $line file2)
   echo $line" "$search > file_output
done < file1`

Comment: `man join` and search here for [linux] [bash] join` (maybe the `[bash]` isn't really needed). But you'll need to sort your files on the key field before using join. If they're already in order, then you're all set. Good luck.

Comment: Ohhh I did not know the join command,

Comment: You do not show what the output should look like for lines in one file not in the other.

Comment: Can you install sqlite3? It's a very simple lightweight database.

Answer (score 0):

Realized you added similar code as below in your posting and were looking for efficient way, given the format of the files join will work straight off here

*# join file1 file2*

*Earlier Response*: You can perhaps extract the first field out of the first file using cat/awk and then look for that in the 2nd file (grep). On finding a match add the two parts. Sometthing as below should help. Although I am doing field 2,3 with cut that part can be improved to read rest of the line

```
for name in `cat file1 | awk '{print $1}'`
do
     result2=`grep $name file2`
     if [ $? -eq 0 ];
     then
         part1=`grep $name file1`
         part2=`echo $result2 | cut -d' ' -f2,3`
         echo "$part1 $part2"
     fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works, but may not be efficient

```
$ head f*
==> f1.txt <==
NUMBER   CODE   CAMP2
1222     aa132   3264
1223     ab124   4283
1224     af121   6224
1225     ag172   9235
1226     aw183   1229

==> f2.txt <==
NUMBER   NAME    CAMP3
1222     Juan     1111
1223     Carlos   2222
1225     Jesus    4444
1226     Mosies   5555


$ awk '{ while(getline line < "f2.txt") {split(line, a, " "); if(a[1] == $1) {print $1, $2, $3, a[2], a[3] }} close("f2.txt"); }' f1.txt

NUMBER CODE CAMP2 NAME CAMP3
1222 aa132 3264 Juan 1111
1223 ab124 4283 Carlos 2222
1225 ag172 9235 Jesus 4444
1226 aw183 1229 Mosies 5555
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '{ if(NR==FNR) {
           r[$1]=substr($0, match($0,/ [^ ]/)+1)
       } else {
           print($0,r[$1])
           r[$1]=""
       }
     } END {
        for (i in r)
            if (r[i]!="")
                print(i,"        . ","    .",r[i])
     }
' filen2 filen1
```

With `filen1` being:

```
NUMBER   CODE   CAMP2
1222     aa132   3264
1223     ab124   4283
1224     af121   6224
1225     ag172   9235
1226     aw183   1229
```

And filen2 being:

```
NUMBER   NAME    CAMP3
1222     Juan     1111
1223     Carlos   2222
1225     Jesus    4444
1226     Moises   5555
1248     Antonio  8888
2185     Pablo    7754
```

You should get this output:

```
NUMBER   CODE   CAMP2 NAME    CAMP3
1222     aa132   3264 Juan     1111
1223     ab124   4283 Carlos   2222
1224     af121   6224 
1225     ag172   9235 Jesus    4444
1226     aw183   1229 Moises   5555
2185         .      . Pablo    7754
1248         .      . Antonio  8888
```

Change the dots into spaces if you do not want dots in the output.